# Why does my GPU run hotter in Ubuntu than in Windows?

Tags: graphics, performance, gpu

I've just installed Ubuntu besides Windows and I've noticed that my Graphics Card fan makes a louder sound when using YouTube on Ubuntu than the sound it makes when playing games on Windows.

Why is that happening and How can I make it calm down a bit? Or is it just excited to be used on such a beautiful thing as Linux :D ?

Comment: Your GPU must be a big fan of Linux that it's fans are not stopping, Linux is just so $exy that she is getting so hot. You can calm her down by giving her a toothbrush

Comment: Joking aside, what graphic card do you have? Because maybe you have to install the appropriate drivers for it to work correctly, because right now it seems that it is working under full load the whole time

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: i have a gtx 960

Comment: So install the drivers from Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 i followed the steps and switch to the other driver and now i can't log in to my ubuntu session ( speaking from windows )

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: @afdelayoub Actually it's UEFI (which replaces the old BIOS) but colloquially we still refer to the new UEFI as "BIOS". That aside, it's hardware dependent. Please check your user's manual as each model is different. Some do it in "OS Selection" where "Windows8/10 = Secure boot enabled" and "Other (or Linux or...) = Secure Boot disabled. Other have it in a unique setting.